# JMX not available for spring boot application when running standalone

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jmx

I have a spring boot application with an embedded Jetty and need to monitor the application using JMX.

I can access JMX infomation with jconsole as long as I start the application inside my windows development environment (JConsole offers the process to connect to on its own)
But as soon as a run the application as executable jar with the parameters below, the ports will not be available and I cannot connect with jconsole

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false 
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=[server ip] 
-Djava.rmi.activation.port=9011
```

netstat -tulpn does neither return port 9010 nor port 9011, and I cannot connect via jconsole.

MBeans etc. are available since I expose the JMX information as JSON, using jolikai, which is working fine but does not fit into our monitoring infrastructure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following parameters.

```
set JMX_OPTIONS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8014 
set JMX_OPTIONS= %JMX_OPTIONS% -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
set JMX_OPTIONS= %JMX_OPTIONS%-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
set JMX_OPTIONS= %JMX_OPTIONS%-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.localConnectorAddress=10.250.0.10
```